# ScriptengineException when string methods are called

Tags: c#, clearscript

When I am using the following snippet, I get a ScrptEngineException, that the object does not support the Property or Method.

```
var engine = new JScriptEngine();
engine.AddHostType("String", typeof(System.String));
engine.ExecuteCommand("test = 'variabel'; test.StartsWith('nice');");
```

I have tried some other Stringfunctions like IndexOf, ToArray (Extension) and some others, but the do not seem to work.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `test` is a JavaScript string, which has no `StartsWith` method. Even if it had been returned from .NET, it would have been converted to a JavaScript string for convenience.

You can add a method that converts a JavaScript string to a .NET string:

```
engine.AddHostObject("host", new HostFunctions());
engine.Execute(@"
    String.prototype.toHost = function() {
        return host.newVar(this.valueOf());
    }
");
```

And then this should work:

```
engine.AddHostType(typeof(Console));
engine.Execute(@"
    test = 'variable';
    Console.WriteLine(test.toHost().StartsWith('var'));
    Console.WriteLine(test.toHost().StartsWith('vaz'));
");
```

BTW, be careful with this:

```
engine.AddHostType("String", typeof(System.String));
```

That hides the built-in JavaScript `String` function and is likely to break things.